# Aperiodic tilings of the plane by squares and rhombi

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, tiling

Consider tilings of the plane by unit squares and by rhombi of unit side length and angles $\pi/3$, $2\pi/3$. It is easy to come up with periodic tilings of the plane - consider the following: [image]
(from  [https://www.public.asu.edu/~aaafp/tiling/hingedtilingtext.html](https://www.public.asu.edu/%7Eaaafp/tiling/hingedtilingtext.html))

It also seems easy to modify a tiling such as this one to obtain (silly and dull) aperiodic tilings of the plane - just take a SW-NE (or NW-SE) square-rhombus-square-rhombus-... frieze, and insert a duplicate of it just to its southeast (or northeast). Repeat.

Questions:

- Are there other aperiodic tilings with these square and rhombi?
- Are there quasiperiodic tilings with these square and rhombi?
- Are there substitution tilings with these square and rhombi?

How would one show any of these not to be possible?

(There are interesting aperiodic tilings of the plane with squares and *other* rhombi - see https://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution/ammann-beenker/ .)

Comment: I'm actually not sure that the "silly and dull" purportedly aperiodic tilings describe above are genuinely aperiodic; at least if we insert only friezes in the SW-NE direction (or a bunch of friezes in one direction and then in the other) we seem to stay in the *closure* of the set of periodic tilings, no?

Comment: You can easily form aperiodic tilings with just the rhombi - you can tile a hexagon with three such in two ways, so you can "fill in" a hexagonal tessellation in uncountably many ways, most aperiodic. Forcing one to use nonzero amount of squares breaks that idea though,

Comment: I see. Is that aperiodic in the stronger sense, though? I thought the standard definition of "T is aperiodic" was "there is an R such that T doesn't agree with any periodic tiling on any disc of radius R". (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_tiling)

Comment: Ah no, it's not. I wasn't familiar with that stricter definition

Comment: Hah - I think I can show there are *no* aperiodic tilings (in the stronger sense of "aperiodic") with these tiles - and, moreover, I can classify all tilings. [They are really boring.] I can give a proof below (I think) if anybody who is not I is interested.

Comment: (This is a bit unfortunate, since IRL square tiles are inexpensive, and rhombus tiles with the angles described are also common.)

Comment: @Wojowu The reason for that definition is that you can build a dynamical system by considering all tilings of the plane which locally look like your tile. Under a suitable topology (the rubber topology) this becomes a topological dynamical system. The stricter definition is saying that this DS does not contain any periodic elements.

Comment: Boring is a vague term here though. Note here that you can tile the strip $[0,1] \times \mathbb R$ with squares and the strip $[0, \sqrt{3}] \times \mathbb R$ with rhombi. Then, given any bi-infinite word on two letters, lets call them $s$ and $r$, you can replace $s$ by an interval of lenght $1$ and $r$ by an interval of lenght $\sqrt{3}$ and then tile the corresponding vertical strips with squares/rhombi. This gives you a tiling of the plane, which is periodic in the vertical direction, which section in the horisontal direction is your bi-infinite word.....

Comment: ...... By this idea you can make the tiling completelly random in one direction (use a bernoulisation to create the word) or to correspond to your favourite symbolic substitution, like for example the Fibonacci substitution... I would not call this boring. The diffraction of the last example would be periodic in one dimension but dense in the other.

Comment: Also, a short comment: this shows that if you replace the rhombi by slightly smaller rhombi with exactly the same angles but irrational side $(1-\epsilon)$, you can create an aperiodic tiling of the plane.

Comment: Also, unless I make a stupid mistake, for any substitution on these two tiles, the inflated square must be divided into squares only (the same argument should hold for rhombi). Indeed, look at the corners, there must be 4 suqares there... Now follow the edges from one corner to the next, you can easily argue that there must be only squares here. After you are done around the boundary you are left with a smaller square, and repeat.

Comment: @NickS Thank you for the explanation, that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Apparently not everybody finds the pattern above to be boring! See https://todobarro.com/suelo/prometheus-iso-10/

Comment: @WlodekKuperberg No :)

Comment: @WlodekKuperberg Aperiodic = there is an R such that there is no disc of radius R has an intersection with the tiling that is identical to its intersection with a periodic tiling. (If you wish: a large enough part of the tiling forces you to continue it in a non-periodic way.)